# Copy Constructor for Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, copy-constructor

So I am attempting to make a copy constructor for a linked list. I have tried a bunch of different methods inside the copy constructor but none of them seem to be working. Can anyone tell me what I should do to improve the code?

```
Stack::Stack(Stack*StkIn)
{
 top = NULL;
 numItems = 0;
 node* oPtr = StkIn->top;
 node* nPtr = top;
 while (oPtr != NULL)
 {
  nPtr->item = oPtr->item;
  nPtr = nPtr->next;
  oPtr = oPtr->next;
 }
}
```

Comment: For one, actually copy things. Your very first iteration is dereferencing a NULL pointer and invoking *undefined behavior*. And copy constructors don't pass their argument by address (pointer), they pass by *reference*. In short, nothing in this copy-ctor is correct.

Comment: Could you suplly your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
Stack::Stack(Stack*StkIn)
{
 top = NULL;
 numItems = 0;
 node* oPtr = StkIn->top;
 node* nPtr = new Stack();
 node* npPtr = NULL;
 while (oPtr != NULL)
 {
 npPtr = new Stack();
  nPtr->item = oPtr->item;
  nPtr->next = npPtr;
  nPtr = npPtr;
  oPtr = oPtr->next;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not a copy constructor. See `Tony D`'s answer

Comment: That's a bit random.  `node* nPtr = = new Stack()` should be `new node()` (and not done if `StkIn`'s `top` is `nullptr`), `top`'s never updated, `numItems` isn't maintained....

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be a copy constructor, the signature should be change to accept a `const` reference:

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack& StkIn)
{
    top = NULL;
    numItems = 0;

    node* oPtr = StkIn.top;
    node* nPtr = top;       // this sets nPtr to NULL
    while (oPtr != NULL)
    {
        nPtr->item = oPtr->item;   // then you dereference nPtr - initially NULL!!!!
        nPtr = nPtr->next;
        oPtr = oPtr->next;
    }
}
```

You need to do a `new node;` inside the loop to allocate memory, *then* set the data members.  And you're not updating `top` to point to the first new node.

Taking a step back, you should learn how to work on these kind of problems.  Write down on paper something like:

```
[oPtr = StkIn.top = NULL]

[oPtr = StkIn.top] ----> [node:{item1,next=NULL]

[oPtr = StkIn.top] ----> [node:{item1,next--]----> [node:{item2,next=NULL]
```

Those are three test cases... if you can prove to yourself that your code works for all three, then it will probably work for any number of nodes in the list.

For each of these, follow your code line by line, working out what the variables would hold, and see if the instructions correctly copy `StkIn` to new memory.  For example, the last one should produce something like:

```
[top] ----> [node:{item1,next--]----> [node:{item2,next=NULL]
```

Following/working out your logic on paper is very useful for these kinds of problems....